# Tricolor Fragment Shader

Tags: three.js, 3d, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm developing an animation using Three.js which simply involves an Icosahedron Buffer Geometry and a Shader Material applied together into a mesh. The goal is to get the object to resemble this:

Vision for final product:

[image: img]

I'm new to GLSL so getting to this point hasn't been easy. I borrowed some code from the shaders used in [this codepen.](https://codepen.io/vcomics/pen/ZjMpOe) The issue with this shader is that the colors rendered are merely distinct outputs of Red, Green, and Blue, whereas I want three specific colors each with their own unique hex value.

Here is a snippet of the fragment shader code that I have tried:

```
uniform int u_color1;
uniform int u_color2;
uniform int u_color3;

void main() {
  float r1 = float(u_color1 / 256 / 256);
  float g1 = float(u_color1 / 256 - int(r1 * 256.0));
  float b1 = float(u_color1 - int(r1 * 256.0 * 256.0) - int(g1 * 256.0));

  float r2 = float(u_color2 / 256 / 256);
  float g2 = float(u_color2 / 256 - int(r1 * 256.0));
  float b2 = float(u_color2 - int(r2 * 256.0 * 256.0) - int(g2 * 256.0));

  float r3 = float(u_color3 / 256 / 256);
  float g3 = float(u_color3 / 256 - int(r3 * 256.0));
  float b3 = float(u_color3 - int(r3 * 256.0 * 256.0) - int(g3 * 256.0));

  vec3 color1 = vec3((r1/255.0) , (g1/255.0) , (b1/255.0) );
  vec3 color2 = vec3((r2/255.0) , (g2/255.0) , (b2/255.0) );
  vec3 color3 = vec3((r3/255.0) , (g3/255.0) , (b3/255.0) );

  vec4 outColor = vec4(r1 /256.0, g1/256.0, b1/256.0, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!